# To read csv/.xlsx files present under DAM in AEM

Tags: java, aem, ftp-client

I have a requirement to read a csv/xlsx file from ftp location into AEM without downloading it. I have tried using inputstream and temp file method but was not successful with the implementation. Then I tried uploading the csv/xlsx file onto the DAM in AEM and tried to read it but that too didn't work.Any pointers or suggestions would be helpful.

```
package mercer.sites.core.servlets;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolverFactory;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.HttpConstants;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.day.cq.dam.api.Asset;
import com.day.cq.dam.api.Rendition;

@Component(service = {
    Servlet.class
}, property = {
    "sling.servlet.methods=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_POST,
    "sling.servlet.paths=" + "/bin/server/ftpkiidsdownload"
})
public class FtpKIIDSDownload extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2936716575012279185 L;
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    public static final String ftpUserName = "Anonymous";
    public static final String ftpPassword = "User@";
    public static final String ftpHost = "intranetftp.mercer.com";

    @Reference
    private ResourceResolverFactory resolverFactory;



    public void doPost(final SlingHttpServletRequest request, final SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.info("hi");
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String newFile = "";
        FTPClient ftpClient = null;
        String fileName = "2018-01-26-Us-Healthcare-Labor-Market-Analysis-Mockup-FINAL.pdf";
        String fileName2 = "footballersclub.xlsx";
        try {
            log.info("hi1");
            ftpClient = getFtpClient();

            inputStream = getdownloadFile("/public/riju/Sandeep/" + fileName2, ftpClient);

            newFile = writeToDam(fileName2, inputStream);
            readExcelFile(newFile);

            response.setStatus(SlingHttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED);
            response.getWriter().print("File uploaded correctly");
            log.info("hello");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.setStatus(SlingHttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            response.sendError(SlingHttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            response.getWriter().print("{\"status:\": \"An error occured on the server\"}");
        } finally {

            ftpClient.logout();
            ftpClient.disconnect();

        }
    }

    public FTPClient getFtpClient() throws SocketException, IOException, ServletException {
        FTPClient ftp = null;

        ftp = new FTPClient();
        ftp.connect(ftpHost);
        reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            ftp.disconnect();
            throw new ServletException("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
        }
        ftp.login(ftpUserName, ftpPassword);
        ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        log.info("hi2 inside FTPCLient");
        return ftp;
    }
    public InputStream getdownloadFile(String remoteFilePath, FTPClient ftp) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {

            is = ftp.retrieveFileStream(remoteFilePath);
            if (is == null) {
                log.info("null");
                return null;
            }

            log.info("hi3 inside getDownloadfile");
            return is;
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    public String writeToDam(String fileName, InputStream is) {
        String newFile = "";
        log.info("hi4 inside write to dam");
        log.info(fileName);
        Map < String, Object > param = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
        param.put(ResourceResolverFactory.SUBSERVICE, "mercerReadService");
        ResourceResolver resolver = null;
        log.info("hi5 inside write but below rs");
        try {
            log.info("inside writetoDam try loop");
            resolver = resolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(param);
            log.info("hi6 inside write but below in try loop");
            com.day.cq.dam.api.AssetManager assetMgr = resolver.adaptTo(com.day.cq.dam.api.AssetManager.class);
            log.info("hi7 inside write but below asset manager");
            if (fileName.endsWith(".pdf")) {
                newFile = "/content/dam/" + fileName;
                log.info("hi8 inside write but below asset manager under new file");
                assetMgr.createAsset(newFile, is, "application/pdf", true);
                log.info(newFile);
            } else if (fileName.endsWith(".xlsx")) {
                fileName = fileName.split("\\.")[0];
                newFile = "/content/dam/temp/" + fileName;
                log.info("hi8 inside write but below asset manager under new file");
                assetMgr.createAsset(newFile, is, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", true);
                log.info(newFile);
            }
            return newFile;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    public void readExcelFile(String fileName) throws SocketException, IOException, ServletException, InvocationTargetException {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
        XSSFSheet sheet = null;
        try {
            Map < String, Object > param = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
            param.put(ResourceResolverFactory.SUBSERVICE, "mercerReadService");
            ResourceResolver resolver = null;
            resolver = resolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(param);
            org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource resource = resolver.getResource(fileName);
            Asset asset = resource.adaptTo(Asset.class);
            Rendition rend = asset.getOriginal();
            File file = rend.adaptTo(File.class);
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator < Row > rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                Iterator < Cell > cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            log.info(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "t");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            log.info(cell.getStringCellValue() + "t");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            workbook.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried running so others can produce the error you have faced. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What the error log shows?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to get any file from AEM Dam.

```
    ResourceResolver resourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
    Resource res = resourceResolver.getResource("/path/to/dam/file");
    Asset asset = res.adaptTo(Asset.class);
    Rendition rendition = asset.getOriginal();
    InputStream inputStream = rendition.adaptTo(InputStream.class);
    String inputString = CharStreams.toString(reader);
```

I have converted to String in the last line given above. But after you get the InputStream, you can do whichever operation you want.
Maybe use some APIs to get the CSV out from it.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue, But i have resolved it with something like this:

Resource original = Objects.requireNonNull(
Objects.requireNonNull(resourceResolver.getResource(filePath)).adaptTo(Asset.class))
.getOriginal();

```
public static XSSFWorkbook getWorkBookFromDAM(Resource original) {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook =null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try (InputStream inputStream = Objects.requireNonNull(original.getChild(JcrConstants.JCR_CONTENT))
                .adaptTo(InputStream.class)) {
             workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Exception in getJsonStringFromDAM method : ", e);
        }
        return workbook;
    }
```

You can do whatever manipulation you want with worksheet.